# How I can fix permission problem with Laravel Forge on deploy

Tags: laravel, deployment, forge

Because even paid plans in Forge don't receive replies from the support when there are problems with their PAID service I have to ask here.

Everything was working perfectly with my Laravel Forge deployment and after some updates in the Forge I was starting to receive this error after every deployment:

```
deploy files successful 
DIR/.forge/provision-15538164.sh: line 48: /tmp/fpmlock: Permission denied 
my post-deployment scripts never run because of this error
```

I tried to change the folder owner to root, forge, etc., without any success. The only way is for this folder to be sent to the project owner, but I have many projects and they all try to write in this lock file.

The problem is the same even for newly installed servers via Forge.

So since there is no support, how I can fix this problem?